# Greater and less than operator in a URL

Tags: json, url, operators

Hello everyone i have a db.json file which i run in http://localhost:3004
The format is like this:

```
[
  {
    "Symbol": "AAPL",
    "prodType": "STK",
    "Market": "Symbol Industries Inc",
    "Country": "US",
    "Quantity": 10,
    "NominalValue": 123.45,
    "AvgPrice": 131.16,
    "PositionCost": 123.87,
    "LastPrice": 123.567,
    "PositionValue": 145.78,
    "TotalValue": 123.347,
    "PortfolioPercentage": 12,
    "ProfitLoss": 1235.09,
    "Results": "12 Dec, 2017",
    "Dividend": "29 Apr, 2017"
  },
  {
    "Symbol": "fsdfsd",
    "prodType": "DER",
    "Market": "Symbol Industries Inc",
    "Country": "Greece",
    "Quantity": 10,
    "NominalValue": 123.45,
    "AvgPrice": 131.16,
    "PositionCost": 123.87,
    "LastPrice": 123.567,
    "PositionValue": 145.78,
    "TotalValue": 123.347,
    "PortfolioPercentage": 12,
    "ProfitLoss": 1235.09,
    "Results": "12 Dec, 2017",
    "Dividend": "29 Apr, 2017"
  }
]
```

i want to make a query to the URL to bring me the records which have total value greater than 100 and lesser than 130 for example but i can't. I use different approaches but no one is working properly. How can i implement such a query in this URL?

Comment: *I use different approaches* can you show at least one of them?

Comment: Of course, first i used the ot operator: http://localhost:3000/accounts?TotalValue=123.347&TotalValue_ot=21....second http://localhost:3000/accounts?TotalValue={"lt":100, "gt":150},

Comment: http://localhost:3004/portfolioList?TotalValue=~lteq~123.347